# Iam unable to get the Alone star icon in the browser

Tags: typescript, glyphicons

I am unable to get the alone star icon in the browser. Here is what I have done:

1. I placed an object in class of `app.component.ts`

   ```
   post = {
     valu:true
   }
   ```
2. I placed the following code in a component that I created, i.e. `star.component.html`

   ```
   <span
   class ="glyphicon" 
   [class.glyphicon-star]="valu"
   [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!valu"
   (click)="onclick()"
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"
   >
   </span>
   ```
3. And the code in `app.component.html`

   ```
   <app-star 
     [valu]="post.valu"
   >

   </app-star>
   ```
4. Placed input decorator in `star.component.ts`

   ```
   @Input() valu:boolean;
   ```

P.S. I have installed bootstrap